# Unable to open the NuGet Package Manager Console

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I try to open the **NuGet Package Manager Console** I get the following error. Am not sure what is preventing the Package Manager Console to open.

```
Each package is licensed to you by its owner. NuGet is not responsible for, nor does it grant any licenses to, third-party packages. Some packages may include dependencies which are governed by additional licenses. Follow the package source (feed) URL to determine any dependencies.

Package Manager Console Host Version 4.5.0.4685

Type 'get-help NuGet' to see all available NuGet commands.

Unable to find fallback package folder 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackagesFallback\'.
```

Here is an additional information from I retrieved from `dotnet --info`:

```
.NET Command Line Tools (2.1.2)

Product Information:
 Version:            2.1.2
 Commit SHA-1 hash:  5695315371

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.15063
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.2\

Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host

  Version  : 2.0.3
  Build    : a9190d4a75f4a982ae4b4fa8d1a24526566c69df
```

After having tried searching for the solution am posting here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Start PowerShell as **Administrator** and run the following command:

```
mkdir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackagesFallback"
```

Then restart Visual Studio and everything should work.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by creating the requested folder.

Hope this works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are connected to the internet when you try to build a project that has new Nuget packages in it that need to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a duplicate package in my package.config file. After removing it, everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was, it was opening on other monitor.